# How to use stock from tablet

Tags: stock

So, sometimes I am a lazy cook. And this is a question for the very lazy days. 
Sometimes I use stock from a tablet. 
I was wondering: If a recipe calls for 'adding stock', is it important that you first make stock from the tablet and then add it to the recipe. Or can you just put in the right amount of (hot) water and the tablet?

I can imagine it does matter in some kind of dishes. But when does is, and when not? And why?

Comment: And I was thinking theres an iPad app to make stock

Comment: I guess I can not make stock from Apples.

Comment: there's a place called NASDAQ that sells Apple stock.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the kind of stock cube. Drier, powdery stock cubes can be crushed and sprinkled in and the appropriate amount of liquid added.

Paste cubes should be broken up (I often chop them with my knife so as not to get sticky stock paste on my fingers) and placed in hot water before adding to the dish, because they don't dissolve as readily as the powdery cubes.

Comment: But that doesn't really answer my question: Does it matter for the dish whether you do this or not? Or you say: It matters but not if it dissolved quick enough?

Comment: @LotteLaat: Well, if you drop the cube in and it doesn't dissolve until you're nearly done cooking, but something in there was supposed to absorb flavor from the broth, that's obviously bad. Otherwise as long as it's dissolved completely, and all that matters is that the flavor be in the liquid, should be fine.